# Remove dll after loading QLibrary

Tags: c++, qt, dllimport

I use QLibrary to resolve symbols in my QT program. I need to update library while application is running. So I try to remove current library file, but file is locked by my application.

```
QLibrary lib("mylib.dll");
if (lib->load())
    myfun = (MyFun) lib.resolve("myfun");
lib.unload();
myfun();
QFile::remove("mylib.dll"); // error on windows, success on linux mylib.so
```

It works fine on linux, but does't work on windows.

I also tried to remove mylib.dll manually when application is running, and get error "file is open in myapp.exe".

I using QT 5.7 with msvc2015 compiller.

Comment: thats just how the filesystems differ under windows and linux.

Comment: `QLibrary::unload()` returns true on success, what is the return value for you?

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to unload the library and then subsequently call into it? One wonders if you are linking to the library with load time linking.